# What is the 'orangey' colour on this pine and how do I remove it?

Tags: wooden-furniture, wood-finishing, pine

I've recently bought some pine furniture which is well built and solid but needs a bit of TLC.

It is also finished with something that gives it a kind of 'orangey' colour. It has some scratches and I much prefer the more natural, paler colour underneath. So I want to remove the finish.

[image] 
[image]

My question is thus three-fold I guess:

1. What do you think the varnish/lacquer/coating is?
2. Can I remove it and if so, how?
3. What would you recommend as a natural coating to protect it but keep the 'natural' colour of the wood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, '[Pumpkin pine](http://www.binghamlumber.com/reclaimed-pumpkin-pine.php)' IS (or can be) a natural, aged color of pine.

Painting is the easiest recourse.

[Formby's](http://www.formbys.com/products/refinisher/) or similar 'refinisher' will strip wood (of varnishes) and leave some patina, after which, a wood bleach (an oxalic acid based, like [Savogran wood bleach](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.savogran.com/pdfs/Wood_Bleach_PD.pdf)) would be called for.

Then, sand and coat with a u/v blocking clear finish.

Repeat in 20 years.

**OR**

Tell every one its an antique and mustn't be tampered with.  Its the best TLC this beauty deserves.

*[Essay on Pumpkin Pine by Richard Mcintosh](http://www.swans.com/library/art9/rmac11.html)*

Comment: They do both look nice.  I wouldn't touch them.

Comment: On doing further research, it seems wax was the only finish normally used.  Pine is notoriously difficult to stain properly.  Dye spraying (as opposed to wiping or brushing) can net a un-blotched finish.

Comment: I am done trying to restain wood furniture.  I'm either keeping it or painting it. I have restained tons of floors but furniture is its own beast and I think it takes artistic talent - or at least I tell myself that.